# Is there a way to detect unused Angular template?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, eslint, karma-jasmine

My goal is to check if `HousingListComponent` or `app-housing-list` template is used or not.

The problem is when I comment `<app-housing-list>` in the `app.component.html`, linter do not tell me that I have dangling component.

What I've tried:

1. use karma, but the test is still successful even if `HousingListComponent` is not declared in AppModule.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
// import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// import { HousingListComponent } from './housing-list/housing-list.component';
// import { HousingLocationService } from './housing-location.service';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        // if lazy to write unit tests
        // if no need to fake service.
        AppModule

        // RouterTestingModule
      ],
      // declarations: [
      //   AppComponent,
      //   HousingListComponent
      // ],
      // providers: [HousingLocationService]
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  it('should use the HousingListComponent in the template', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection

    const compiled = fixture.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
    const housingListElement = compiled.querySelector('app-housing-list');

    expect(housingListElement).toBeTruthy(); // Check if <app-housing-list> element is present in the template
  });
});
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HousingListComponent } from './housing-list/housing-list.component';
import { HousingLocationService } from './housing-location.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HousingListComponent <= main concern
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [HousingLocationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<main>
    <header><img src="../assets/logo.svg" alt="fairhouse">Fairhouse</header>
    <section>
        <!-- 
        The locationList attribute must be enclosed in square brackets ( [ ] ) 
        so that Angular can dynamically bind the value of the locationList property 
        to a variable or expression. 
        Otherwise, Angular treats the value on the right-hand side of the equals sign as a string. 
    -->
    <!-- 
        The $event is provided by Angular when dealing with event handlers in templates. 
        The $event argument is an object of type HousingLocation 
        because that is what we set the EventEmitter's type parameter to be. 
    -->
        <!-- <app-housing-list [locationList]="housingLocationList" -->
            <!-- (locationSelectedEvent)="updateSelectedLocation($event)"></app-housing-list> -->

        <article>
            <!-- 
                If you apply the ngIf directive to the article element directly, 
                it causes a layout shift when the user makes the first selection. 
                To improve this experience, you can wrap the location details in another element 
                that is a child of the article. 
                This element has no styling or function and just adds weight to the DOM. 
                To avoid that, you can use ng-container. 
                You can apply directives to it, but it won't show up in the final DOM. 
            -->
            <ng-container *ngIf="selectedLocation">
                <img [src]="selectedLocation.photo">
                <p>{{selectedLocation.name}}</p>
                <p>Available Units: {{selectedLocation.availableUnits}}</p>
                <p>{{selectedLocation.city}}, {{selectedLocation.state}}</p>
                <p>{{selectedLocation.laundry ? "Has laundry" : "Does Not have laundry"}}</p>
                <p>{{selectedLocation.wifi ? "Has wifi" : "Does Not have wifi"}}</p>
            </ng-container>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This test should fail. I would try commenting out all of `app.component.html` and see what happens then or having very little HTML.